How do I find the documents where plRecord.rrn = glRecord.rrn
I have collection of 3 documents as below:
{
  "_id": "425540010681",
  "plRecord": {
    "amount": "300",
    "date": {
      "$date": "2024-09-09T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "trace": "83108",
    "rrn": "425540010681",
    "dataType": "in"
  },
  "_class": "com.demo.model.Test"
}
{
  "_id": "425575508081",
  "plRecord": {
    "amount": "200",
    "date": {
      "$date": "2024-09-09T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "trace": "83105",
    "rrn": "425575508081",
    "dataType": "out"
  },
  "glRecord": {
    "amount": "200",
    "rrn": "425575508081",
    "dataType": "GL"
  },
  "_class": "com.demo.model.Test"
}
{
  "_id": "425540010682",
  "glRecord": {
    "amount": "500",
    "rrn": "425540010682",
    "dataType": "GL"
  },
  "_class": "com.demo.model.Test"
}

How do I find the documents where
plRecord.rrn = glRecord.rrn 

and also those two are not equal
I tried
{ "glRecord.rrn": { $exists: false } } 

to get second part in a way i.e. if it doesnt exist means not equal - of course partially true :( . But couldn't get my head around how to find where 2 are equal.
I am noob when it comes to Mongo - so excuse me if its too basic.
